# button make the same position with other element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have an HTML layout that is divided into two columns as shown below:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <form id="bookform">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="datefrom" class="form-label">Date From</label>
                        <input id="datefrom" name="datafrom" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="dateto" class="form-label">Date To</label>
                        <input id="dateto" name="dateto" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <label for="bookname" class="form-label">Book Name</label>
                        <input id="bookname" name="bookname" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <label for="batchno" class="form-label">Batch No</label>
                        <input id="batchno" name="batchno" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label for="address" class="form-label">Address</label>
                        <input id="address" name="address" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-auto">
            <div class="row">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success">Excel Export</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The output is
[image]
I want the button to be aligned with the bottom of the textboxes. Can you please help me with how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im not sure if this a good way to do

you can add `style` inside the button,
it would be like

```html
<button class="btn btn-outline-success" style="padding-top: 1rem;">
```

or

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-success pt-1">
```

ref: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/#notation

*note: change the number as you need*

Comment: no the button height will auto increase, I just want move the button , not resize the button

Comment: change the padding to margin

Answer (score 0):

You can align [vertically and horizontally](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#vertical-alignment) the content of a column. Maybe the class `align-self-end` could solve your problem:

```css
<div class="col-md-auto align-self-end">
    <div class="row">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success ">
      Excel Export
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```